# Can't figure this function composition code

Tags: python

I wrote a code that gets n functions and composites them together. If the function doesnt recieve any input it returns the "x" which we called the lambda functions with.(example- compose()(3) # will return 3)
this is my code, i simply cant seem to see the problem:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    if len(funcs)==0:
        return lambda x: x
    else:
        for i in funcs[-1:0:-1]:

            return lambda x: funcs[0](funcs[i](x))
```

Comment: what is i?  A number or a function?

Comment: its an index that runs on all the function from the end to the start. cause what i want to do is f1(f2(f3(......fn(x)))

Comment: Why do you always return from the for loop after the first iteration?

Comment: And `funcs[-1:0:-1]` is better written `reversed(funcs[1:])` IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have three functions:

```
def f1(x):
    return 'f1 %s' % x

def f2(x):
    return 'f2 %s' % x

def f3(x):
    return 'f3 %s' % x
```

Then we have a function compose:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    def f(x):
        ret = x
        for func in funcs[::-1]:
            ret = func(ret)
        return ret
    return f
```

We can use it like this:

```
F = compose(f1, f2, f3)
print F('x')
```

It will print out:

```
f1 f2 f3 x
```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to implement functional composition is this:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    def _inner(x):
        functools.reduce(lambda acc, f: f(acc), funcs, x)
    return _inner
```

However, in order to fix your code, you might do this:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    if not funcs:    # preferred to checking if len is 0
        return lambda x: x
    else:
        return lambda x: funcs[0](compose(*funcs[1:])(x))
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want the `reversed` there

Comment: @Eric Fixed, I thought that it didn't work without the reversal, but then realised that it does.

Comment: You could equally write it `lambda x: compose(*funcs[:-1])(funcs[-1](x))`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are talking about

```
def fn1(x):
    return x+1
def fn2(x):
    return x**2
def fn3(x):
    return math.sin(x)**0.5

def apply(my_list_of_stuff):
    if len(my_list_of_stuff) == 1:
         return my_list_of_stuff[0]
    return my_list_of_stuff[0](apply(my_list_of_stuff[1:]))

apply([fn1,fn2,fn3,7]) # -> fn1(fn2(fn3(7)))
```

assuming I understood what you are asking

Comment: Composition is `combined_f = compose([fn1,fn2,fn3])` `combined_f(7)`

Answer (score 0):

Function composition can be elegantly achieved using [reduce](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). You can use the *initializer* argument to achieve your no-input condition too:

```
import functools

def compose(*funcs):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), funcs, lambda x: x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to implement this is:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    chain = lambda f, g: lambda *a, **kw: f(g(*a, **kw))
    return reduce(chain, funcs, lambda x: x)
```

Which will return a new function that is the composition of the list of functions passed to it. If you don't care about kwargs, you can do:

```
def compose(*funcs):
    chain = lambda f, g: lambda *a: f(g(*a))
    return reduce(chain, funcs, lambda x: x)
```

Example:

```
>>> def compose(*funcs):
...     chain = lambda f, g: lambda *a: f(g(*a))
...     return reduce(chain, funcs, lambda x: x)
...
>>> remove_newlines = compose(lambda l: "".join(l), lambda s: s.split("\n"))
>>> remove_newlines("hello\n world")
'hello world'
```

Note: In python3, reduce has been moved out of the stdlib into functools, so you will need to do `from functools import reduce`